# Localhost refuse connection Wampserver

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

After installing wampserver, I tried accessing localhost and apparently it doesn't seem to work. It says that localhost refuses connexion. Here's what I've done.

1. Check if port 80 was used and I don't have any Skype and IIS is using another port. No service are actually using port 80.
2. Changed these lines in httpd-conf file

   ```
   Listen 0.0.0.0:80
   Listen [::0]:80
   ```

   to

   ```
   Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
   Listen [::0]:8080
   ```

   and

   ```
   ServerName localhost:80
   ```

   to
       ServerName localhost:8080

   restart all services and typed http://localhost:8080 and still doesn't work.
3. Visual Studio 2012 : VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe is already installed.
4. Searched everywhere and still doesn't help me. Wampserver icon stays red.

Help will be greatly appreciated, I've searched for many hours and it won't work, I'm desperate.

P.-S. I'm using Windows 7 Professional

Comment: You are using Windows, so you should check if the "Server" service is up and running. Without this you won't get an answer.

Comment: If I go on `Apache > Service Administration`, the `Start/Resume Services` option is disabled. Is that normal?

Comment: Possibly. Have you installed is as a service?

Comment: It also says when I hover over the wampserver icon, _"local server - None of the two services are running"_. I tried clicking on Start all Services and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I installed WAMPSERVER (32 BITS & PHP 5.6.15) 3

Comment: Have you checked the "Server" service? It allows Windows to work as a server and it must be checked.

Comment: How do you check that?

Comment: Look for it among the other services.

Comment: I do not have Windows server installed. My plan is not to transform my computer into a web server, I just want to use wampserver, that's all.

Comment: I haven't said that. It's not "Windows server". It's a service named "Server", which allows your Windows station to act as a server to respond to localhost calls.

Comment: Well after searching for 'server' in my list of programs, I get 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB'

Comment: Not on your list of installed programs. In the SERVICES...

Comment: Yes I have the Server service started.

Comment: Read the Duplicate link at the top of your question

Comment: You know what, I'm going to uninstall  and reinstall wampserver and reinstall it since I can't find the solution.

Comment: Make sure you have ALL the MSVC Runtime libraries installed, before you re-install

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hum you mean installing all MSVC Runtime librairies so every versions of it even the older one?